# iOS hangs when calling Texture2D.readPixels

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, texture2d

I'm attempting to draw a `RenderTexture` into a `Texture2D` with the goal of saving it to disk. This approach has been working in the OSX editor, as well as on Android.

I don't see any errors in the XCode console, and my app becomes completely frozen when I call `Texture2D.ReadPixels()`

Here's a summary of the code:

```
    // declaring variables...
    RenderTexture outputTexture;
    RenderTextureFormat RTFormat = RenderTextureFormat.ARGB32;

    // use an appropriate format for render textures
    if(SystemInfo.SupportsRenderTextureFormat(RenderTextureFormat.ARGBFloat)){
        RTFormat = RenderTextureFormat.ARGBFloat;
    }else if(SystemInfo.SupportsRenderTextureFormat(RenderTextureFormat.ARGBHalf)){
        RTFormat = RenderTextureFormat.ARGBHalf;
    }

    // create instance of output texture
    outputTexture = new RenderTexture (res.x, res.y, 0, RTFormat);

    // in Update, draw stuff to outputTexture
    Graphics.Blit (outputTexture, canvasTexture);
    Graphics.Blit (canvasTexture, outputTexture, material);

    // later... user wants to save the image
    // draw rendertexture to a Texture2D so we can write to disk
    RenderTexture.active = outputTexture;
    tmpTexture = new Texture2D (outputTexture.width, outputTexture.height, TextureFormat.ARGB32, false);
    tmpTexture.ReadPixels (new Rect (0, 0, outputTexture.width, outputTexture.height), 0, 0, false);
    tmpTexture.Apply ();
    RenderTexture.active = null;
```

I have tried using a variety of `RenderTextureFormat` and `TextureFormat`, but nothing seems to work!

Comment: Where are you calling this code? Is this within a custom function or a Unity Callback method?

Comment: Also, Which device are you testing on? Check if you are going out of memory. RenderTexture is an expensive method.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is being caused by your render texture format call. Something similar happened to be before.

This bit of code assigns a default texture format, then alters the default format if the currently executing environment supports it (my comments are added)

```
//set a default render texture of  RenderTextureFormat.ARGB32;
RenderTextureFormat RTFormat = RenderTextureFormat.ARGB32;

// if my system supports it, switch to either ARGBFloat or ARGBHalf

// use an appropriate format for render textures
if(SystemInfo.SupportsRenderTextureFormat(RenderTextureFormat.ARGBFloat)){
    RTFormat = RenderTextureFormat.ARGBFloat;
}else if(SystemInfo.SupportsRenderTextureFormat(RenderTextureFormat.ARGBHalf)){
    RTFormat = RenderTextureFormat.ARGBHalf;
}
```

However, when you actually later define your temp texture to fill with ReadPixels(), you only define it one way (again, my comments added)

```
//define a new tmpTexture container, ALWAYS with a TextureFormat of ARGB32
tmpTexture = new Texture2D (outputTexture.width, outputTexture.height, TextureFormat.ARGB32, false);
```

Thus on some systems (whichever supports the format), you're trying to readPixels() from one texture format into another. This is probably causing your issue.

You can fix this by also dynamically changing the format of the destination texture. So in the first section, you would change it to:

```
RenderTextureFormat RTFormat = RenderTextureFormat.ARGB32;

//add another variable here for the destination Texture format
var destinationFormat = TextureFormat.ARGB32;


// use an appropriate format for render textures
if(SystemInfo.SupportsRenderTextureFormat(RenderTextureFormat.ARGBFloat)){
    RTFormat = RenderTextureFormat.ARGBFloat;

    //also set destination format
    destinationFormat = TextureFormat.RGBAFloat;
}else if(SystemInfo.SupportsRenderTextureFormat(RenderTextureFormat.ARGBHalf)){
    RTFormat = RenderTextureFormat.ARGBHalf;

    //also set destination format
    destinationFormat = TextureFormat.RGBAHalf;
}
```

and then of course, later consume the dynamically set format when declaring the destination object:

```
//define a new tmpTexture container, with a dynamically set destination format that always matches the input texture
tmpTexture = new Texture2D (outputTexture.width, outputTexture.height, destinationFormat, false);
```

Let me know if you still have issues in the comments.

Comment: Wow, thank you for such a detailed post. My issue ended up being super simple, and you helped me see it. I had tried setting the destinationFormat to TextureFormat.RGFloat! I'm actually kind of baffled that it was working on Android, despite this glaring error. I'm going to submit an edit to your answer, for accuracy and posterity sake.

Comment: Sorry, I preemptively accepted your answer. I got it to run once, but then rebuilding with the same code failed again.

Comment: Same thing, nothing in the XCode output? And still runs on Android?

Comment: I have a hunch its still related to the dynamic switching calls. Can you try commenting out all the if(SupportsRenderTextureFormat) statements, and see if it runs on device? Also, can you put a few calls to Debug.Log() in the code to see in the Xcode console exactly which line is stopping exection (unless you're sure its the ReadPixels line)?

Comment: I tried using RenderTexture.default, and not setting the TextureFormat on the Texture2D, but still no luck. Also tried commenting out the support detection block, and using the initial values. I have littered the code with logs, and it's definitely the ReadPixels line that borks it. I can test some stuff on android later today, but it seems much more forgiving than iOS

Comment: hmmm... Might be the timing of the screengrab then. You can try putting the block of code where the user is saving the image is into an OnPostRender() call, or place it in a Coroutine,  Then at the start of the coroutine call yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123985/discussion-between-hbomb-and-posit-labs).